# list view java.lang.IllegalStateException even after calling notifyDataSetCanged();

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, illegalstateexception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

my list-view contains huge data`s

am calling the bellow code using handler when the data is changed in the list

```
  listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but i get the same error some times and not every time i load it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

the question **is not where the adapter update**, it should be: **the time the adapter update**.

it look likes: your data bind to the adapter has be changed, and the ui have be updated, so this time, the system find the data changed but can't invoke the `notifyDataSetChanged`.

so, suggestion when you change the adapter's data, invoke `notifyDataSetChanged` immediately,

or

dont directed change the adapter's data in your thread, you should send the data to the `hanlder`, and in the `handler` using the data to replace or change the adapter's data and `notifyDataSetChanged`.

so anyway, suggestion get the data can run in background thread, and update the data , `notifyDataSetChanged` used in ui thread.

Comment: am not changing the adapters data from background thread.. also i am calling notifyDataSetChanged when ever the content of the list which is given to the adapter is changed.. i get this error only when huge datas like more than 500+ datas getting loaded into the list

Comment: so, can you describe how do you update the adapter's data shortly?

Comment: i change the list in the background thread which in turn given to the adapter initially.. after changing i call the handler(UI Thread) in handler i cal notifyDataSetChanged().. this is the one exactly i do but i get this exception while huge data`s are there but i dint get this error with small(upto 300 list items) amount of data`s

i call this notifyDataSetCahnged for refreshing my list with new or updated data`s

Comment: `i change the list in the background thread  which in turn given to the adapter initially`, if you just update the list's data ,it maybe ok, but if change the list's size, like add some item, in some rare time, it has some problem, so when you want to change the list's size, can you send the new data to the `hanlder`, and update in `handler` ?

Comment: no am not adding items to the list but i change the data`s with some modifications

Answer (score 0):

the error is quite clear. You have not to call   `listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from a thread different of the UI thread.

Comment: Adding to it, you can call `listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from a Non UI Thread using `runOnUiThread()`

Comment: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread,**bold** `but only from the UI thread`

Comment: we should change only from UI thread.. am changing from UI thread only

Answer (score 0):

Modify the arguments of the adapter in runOnUIThread() or use a handler to notify the adapter that the dataset has changed.

Comment: i used handler for notify see the below comment in answer number 3