# list view java.lang.IllegalStateException even after calling notifyDataSetCanged() gives the same error

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, illegalstateexception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Note : this question is already asked and i dint get a working answer

my list-view contains huge data`s

am calling the bellow code using handler when the data is changed in the list

```
 listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but i get the same error some times and not every time i load it thanks in advance

Comment: Are you updating your UI other than Main thread............

Comment: possible duplicate of [list view java.lang.IllegalStateException even after calling notifyDataSetCanged();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241765/list-view-java-lang-illegalstateexception-even-after-calling-notifydatasetcanged) Please don't ask the same question again.

Comment: @luksprong am asking the same question because i dint get a correct answer yet.. tr are no more visitors as there are 3 answers

Comment: am not updateing my ui in the background thread

Answer (score 0):

use below snippet where you want to update UI with in the thred

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            //update UI

                       }
                    });
```

Comment: if i change my code this way while loading my UI stucks for a while to load huge data`s... my datas my be 500+ listView items

Answer (score 0):

since there 2 threads (UI thread,handler Thread) this error is coming remove that Handler since its work in background .write the code in UI thread only(Its a main thread).

Comment: can you get me a sample code.. i mean how to run in the main thread

Comment: Write the code in one method call it from onCreate(); or any Onclick Listener (if u ve)but not in ASyncTask or etc.

Comment: i do some background process for loading some data`s in a separate thread and after loading i should notify the listview.. get me a clear way to cal it from UI thread.. its not possible to recall onCreate

Comment: this update should be done at a particular time ... tel me what should i do

Comment: Then both Threads should be synchronized means UI Thread should not be called before data change.

Comment: yup you are rite but how should i run notifyDataSetChanged() in UI thread